# How to get the Jabber ID for a Multi User Chat nick

Tags: java, xmpp, smack

I'm trying to get the Jabber ID for a nick in a multi user chat, but the following code returns only null:

```
class JabberMUCMessageListenerAdapter implements PacketListener {

    private final MultiUserChat muc;

    public JabberMUCMessageListenerAdapter(MultiUserChat muc) {
         this.muc = muc;
    }

    @Override
    public void processPacket(Packet p) {
        if (p instanceof Message) {

            final Message msg = (Message) p;

            String jid = muc.getOccupant(msg.getFrom()).getJid(); // returns null

            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You want to get *real* JabberID or "local" (eg. *room@muc.example.com/nick*)?

Comment: I think it's the 'real' ID (what is a 'local' ID)?
Actually, I found out what I was doing wrong:
the conference room was configured so, that only moderators could see the real ID. Don't know if that is a synonymous with an 'anonymous' conference room.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/muc/Occupant.html

> The full JID and nickname are optional.

Comment: "If this information was extracted from a presence and the room is semi or full-anonymous then the answer will be null."
The 1st part is true, but I don't think that the room is anonymous (how do I find it out, if it is?)

Using Pidgin I can access the JID, so there must be a way using Smack, too, mustn't it?